# error: RPC failed; HTTP 504 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT

Tags: git, heroku, push

I'm a Taiwanese student and my english grammarly is not good
,but I can understand what you say.
I want to use git to push my file(3GB) to heroku but failed.

I tried.

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 800000000.

git config --add remote.heroku.proxy "".

git config --global http.proxy ''<<
```

When I `git push heroku master` and then it showed fatal:

> unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/pushboss.git/': Could not
>   resolve proxy: ''.

so I have to type `git config --global --unset http.proxy.`

this is my error message:

> error: RPC failed; HTTP 504 curl 22 The requested URL returned error:
>   504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heroku's file system has a [500MB limit](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#slug-size) for your app and its components. Whilst it is possible to store static files within that, you are encouraged to use third party storage (such as AWS S3 / Azure Blobs etc) for anything other than code, such as images, video, and other media.

I would guess that your git errors are due to the 3GB file far exceeding the 500MB limit Heroku has for the whole app!

Comment: thank you for your answering,I thought no one will answer me,so I hadn't open the stackoverflow whatever thank you

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel my response answered your question, please mark it as the answer, it'd help me too. :)

Comment: I have the same thing, but my slug size is 220 MB

Answer (score 0):

The error 504 is returned, when there is a gateway timeout or in simpler terms, weak internet or no internet connection.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: in my case, I want to push codes to an internal gitlab server. so neither poor internet connection nor large files are my problem. what is the problem in your opinion?